# Dynamic Allocation of huge 3D arrays

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I am working on a project where I need to create a 3D array, some 2D and 1D arrays. The 3D array represents discrete co-ordinates in space and I need lots of points for my problem. The array size will be around 2000*2000*2000. I need store 'double' values in these arrays. Can anyone suggest an efficient scheme to implement this in C?

Thanks in advance

```
/***********************************************************
 *  Copyright Univ. of Texas M.D. Anderson Cancer Center
 *  1992.
 *
 *  Some routines modified from Numerical Recipes in C,
 *  including error report, array or matrix declaration
 *  and releasing.
 ****/
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <malloc.h>

/***********************************************************
 *  Report error message to stderr, then exit the program
 *  with signal 1.
 ****/
void nrerror(char error_text[])

{
  fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",error_text);
  fprintf(stderr,"...now exiting to system...\n");
  exit(1);
}

/***********************************************************
 *  Allocate an array with index from nl to nh inclusive.
 *
 *  Original matrix and vector from Numerical Recipes in C
 *  don't initialize the elements to zero. This will
 *  be accomplished by the following functions.
 ****/
double *AllocVector(short nl, short nh)
{
  double *v;
  short i;

  v=(double *)malloc((unsigned) (nh-nl+1)*sizeof(double));
  if (!v) nrerror("allocation failure in vector()");

  v -= nl;
  for(i=nl;i<=nh;i++) v[i] = 0.0;   /* init. */
  return v;
}

/***********************************************************
 *  Allocate a matrix with row index from nrl to nrh
 *  inclusive, and column index from ncl to nch
 *  inclusive.
 ****/
double **AllocMatrix(short nrl,short nrh,
                     short ncl,short nch)
{
  short i,j;
  double **m;

  m=(double **) malloc((unsigned) (nrh-nrl+1)
                        *sizeof(double*));
  if (!m) nrerror("allocation failure 1 in matrix()");
  m -= nrl;

  for(i=nrl;i<=nrh;i++) {
    m[i]=(double *) malloc((unsigned) (nch-ncl+1)
                        *sizeof(double));
    if (!m[i]) nrerror("allocation failure 2 in matrix()");
    m[i] -= ncl;
  }

  for(i=nrl;i<=nrh;i++)
    for(j=ncl;j<=nch;j++) m[i][j] = 0.0;
  return m;
}

/***********************************************************
 *  Allocate a 3D array with x index from nxl to nxh
 *  inclusive, y index from nyl to nyh and z index from nzl to nzh
 *  inclusive.
 ****/
double ***Alloc3D(short nxl,short nxh,
                     short nyl,short nyh,
                         short nzl, short nzh)
{
  double ***t;
  short i,j,k;


  t=(double ***) malloc((unsigned) (nxh-nxl+1)*sizeof(double **));
  if (!t) nrerror("allocation failure 1 in matrix()");
  t -= nxl;

  for(i=nxl;i<=nxh;i++) {
    t[i]=(double **) malloc((unsigned) (nyh-nyl+1)*sizeof(double *));
    if (!t[i]) nrerror("allocation failure 2 in matrix()");
    t[i] -= nyl;
    for(j=nyl;j<=nyh;j++) {
         t[i][j]=(double *) malloc((unsigned) (nzh-nzl+1)*sizeof(double));
         if (!t[i][j]) nrerror("allocation failure 3 in matrix()");
         t[i][j] -= nzl;}

  }

  for(i=nxl;i<=nxh;i++)
    for(j=nyl;j<=nyh;j++)
       for(k=nzl; k<=nzh;k++) t[i][j][k] = 0.0;
  return t;
}
/***********************************************************
 *Index to 3D array.
 ****/
long index(int x, int y, int z, int Size)
{
     return (Size*Size*x + Size*y + z);
}
/***********************************************************
 *  Release the memory.
 ****/
void FreeVector(double *v,short nl,short nh)
{
  free((char*) (v+nl));
}

/***********************************************************
 *  Release the memory.
 ****/
void FreeMatrix(double **m,short nrl,short nrh,
                short ncl,short nch)
{
  short i;

  for(i=nrh;i>=nrl;i--) free((char*) (m[i]+ncl));
  free((char*) (m+nrl));
}


/***********************************************************
 *  Release the memory.
 ****/
void Free3D(double ***t,short nxl,short nxh,
                short nyl,short nyh, short nzl, short nzh)
{
  short i,j;

  for(i=nxh;i>=nxl;i--)
   {for(j=nyl;j>=nyl;j--) free((char*) (t[i][j]+nzl));
    free((char*) (t[i]+nyl));
   }
  free((char*) (t+nxl));
}

***********************************************************************************

void InitOutputData(InputStruct In_Parm, OutStruct * Out_Ptr)
{
  short nz = In_Parm.nz;
  short nr = In_Parm.nr;
  short na = In_Parm.na;
  short nl = In_Parm.num_layers;
  short size = nr/2*nr/2*nz;
  /* remember to use nl+2 because of 2 for ambient. */

  if(nz<=0 || nr<=0 || na<=0 || nl<=0)
    nrerror("Wrong grid parameters.\n");

  /* Init pure numbers. */
  Out_Ptr->Rsp = 0.0;
  Out_Ptr->Rd  = 0.0;
  Out_Ptr->A   = 0.0;
  Out_Ptr->Tt  = 0.0;

  /* Allocate the arrays and the matrices. */
  //Out_Ptr->Rd_ra = AllocMatrix(0,nr-1,0,na-1);
  //Out_Ptr->Rd_r  = AllocVector(0,nr-1);
  //Out_Ptr->Rd_a  = AllocVector(0,na-1);

  Out_Ptr->A_xyz1 = AllocVector(0,size-1);
  Out_Ptr->A_xyz2 = AllocVector(0,size-1);
  Out_Ptr->A_xyz3 = AllocVector(0,size-1);
  Out_Ptr->A_xyz4 = AllocVector(0,size-1);
  Out_Ptr->A_xz  = AllocMatrix(0,nr-1,0,nz-1);
  Out_Ptr->A_z   = AllocVector(0,nz-1);
  Out_Ptr->A_l   = AllocVector(0,nl+1);

  Out_Ptr->Tt_ra = AllocMatrix(0,nr-1,0,na-1);
  Out_Ptr->Tt_r  = AllocVector(0,nr-1);
  Out_Ptr->Tt_a  = AllocVector(0,na-1);
}
```

Above is the code for allocating the arrays and the function to call them. The call which fails is 'Out_Ptr->A_xyz1 = AllocVector(0,size-1);' when size is more than approx. 7000.

Comment: Is it going to be a sparse array?

Comment: Do the coordinates represent a regular grid? i.e. Must you store the values or can they be calculated when needed from a grid-spacing within an extents rectangle?

Comment: Do you need to access the array mostly in sequence or random access? You could memory-map parts of a big file to store the values. Can't do random access then though.

Comment: don't declare with auto scope i.e inside a function. Stack overflow will happen.

Comment: Not a sparse array. Need random access. Yeah could mem map to a file, but accessing the such a big file will be a pain. Not declared with autoscope.

Comment: @acraig5075: I need to store the values in the grid, they cannot be calculated a function of the grid spacing.

Comment: How long will you be holding this 3d array in memory?

Comment: as long as my code runs. Then i write the array into a txt file. I was planning on writing the array in each step, so that i dont need to use such a huge chunk of mem, but my code already runs for 50 hrs. I dont want to increase run time more.

Comment: Do you realize that you're trying to allocate 2000x2000x2000x8 = 64 GB? No wonder you run out of memory!

Comment: Yup, I know! That's exactly why I was searching for alternate methods..@AntoineMathys My question now is can mmap() handle such a large file?

Comment: Try Boost.MultiArray, although its for C++. It will make your life easier for handling 3D arrays of that huge size. Its 64 GB and since you want to store the entire 64 GB as double, you definitely have to have that much memory or create swaps that large.

Comment: @AntoineMathys. If malloc() uses mmap() why does my program quit when trying to allocate the vector? In AllocVector(), v is NULL, hence the code goes into the condition and exits.

Answer (score 2):

If they are a fixed size (or at least a fixed maximum size) at run time and they are bigger than physical RAM then you may as well use a memory mapped file. The access is at least as quick as RAM+swap and you get the data serialised to disk for free. You can also map views of regions (ie windows) of mapped files that are overall larger than your address space.

If you need a large number of cells because you need high detail in some regions, but not uniformly, you could consider an octree. Then you can store progressively finer resolution in some parts and you have the option to reorder to optimise access to regions that are nearby in 3D - this is very common in things like CFD or medical imaging.

Comment: malloc is not able to allocate such a huge chunk. I have never used mmap(). let me give it a try and reply. Thanks a lot.

Comment: pitc, if you are on a 32bit platform the 2000^3 is bigger than the address space, so you either have to deal with planes/rows/cols separately or use mapped views, or switch to 64bit!

Comment: Yeah got that part, but I was not able to even allocate a 100*100*100 array using malloc(). Now, I am thinking problem is not with malloc. I will add my code to the post.

Comment: The problem is malloc needs a single uninterupted block of memory that big! You need to malloc each 2d plane (or possible even each row) separately and then make an array of arrays. That way maloc can finf space for 100x100 blocks of memory anywhere

Comment: Tried that too. Look at Alloc 3D. Same problem when I try to use that function too.

Comment: @pitc 100x100x100 floats is still 4Gb, what platform are you on? although you can do tricks to window a very large file in a 32bit OS you really need to use 64bit for this kind of application.

Comment: windows server 2008, 64 bit. Tried it on linux server 64 bit too. Same issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for mmap! Your array is 64 GB - much too big to fit in RAM all at once. Luckily, we can force the kernel to do all the heavy lifting for us.

Here's some (admittedly untested) code:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE ((off_t)2000*2000*2000*8)

static inline off_t idx(off_t x, off_t y, off_t z)
{
    return 2000*2000*x + 2000*y + z;
}

int main()
{
    int fd = open("my_huge_array.dat", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);

    // We have to write to the end of the file for the size to be set properly.
    lseek(fd, ARRAY_SIZE - 1, SEEK_SET);
    write(fd, "", 1);

    double* my_huge_array = mmap(NULL, ARRAY_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    // Now play with the array!
    my_huge_array[idx(4, 7, 9)] = 12;
    my_huge_array[idx(0, 0, 0)] = my_huge_array[idx(4, 7, 9)] * 2;

    // Close it up. Don't leak your fd's!
    munmap(my_huge_array, ARRAY_SIZE);
    close(fd);
    remove("my_huge_array.dat");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if I need to keep the map open till my code ends. Run time now is around 50hrs. Is that okay? Or do I need to close it and open with every write.

Comment: You can close it whenever you want. 50 hours is okay.

The kernel manages all memory -> disk activity with what I assume is an LRU cache.

Comment: @pitc - another advantage of mmap, every 10-15 minutes have it flush to disk, and serialize any other data values you need. Then if you have a failure you could write code that recovers from the saved point

Comment: Thanks let me try mmap()and get back to you.

Comment: How do I create the map if I want to call the creation from another function, keep the map alive while some other functions add data to it via pointers and then close the map later, using another function?

Comment: Keep the fd in a global variable, or return a struct of { fd, double*, size } in your allocation function.